# Problems with date function when migrating from SQL Server to POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I have been trying to replicate this SQL Server query on Postgres:

```
MONTH(QC.ModifiedDate) >= Month(GETDATE()) 
AND YEAR(QC.ModifiedDate) >= YEAR((GETDATE()))
```

I ended up with this long and not so good looking query

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM QC.ModifiedDate) >= date_part('month', (SELECT current_timestamp)) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM QC.ModifiedDate) >= date_part('year', (SELECT current_timestamp));
```

It does not seem to work too. Any suggestions please?

Comment: As a side note the logic you have for T-SQL is far from ideal; you shouldn't be applying functions to your columns in the `WHERE` if you want a SARGable query.

Comment: @Larnu thank you, I will fix it.

Comment: Agreed with @Larnu I'm not even sure the current logic does what you think it does, it currently fails on months in the next years but before the current month, such as Jan 2022. The logic you should probably be trying to replicate is `QC.ModifiedDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)`

Comment: For T-SQL something like `QC.ModifiedDate >= DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-1))` would be far for performant.

Comment: There is no m in my alias, @EegiiEnkhtaivan ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want apply the same logic of your TSQL query to a PostgreSQL query then your code is correct, although you can simplify it by removing the inner `SELECT` for `current_timestamp`:

```
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM QC.ModifiedDate) >= date_part('month', current_timestamp) 
AND 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM QC.ModifiedDate) >= date_part('year', current_timestamp)
```

But if the logic is:

> return all rows with `ModifiedDate` in the current month and later

then it is simpler:

```
QC.ModifiedDate >= date_trunc('month', current_timestamp)
```

because `date_trunc('month', current_timestamp)` returns a timestamp of the 1st day of the current month.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest form I can think of:

```
select date_trunc('month', '03/12/2021'::date) >= date_trunc('month', current_date);

-- Where date_trunc yields:

select date_trunc('month', current_date);

       date_trunc       
------------------------
 2021-02-01 00:00:00-08
```

Comment: I would suggest to not `date_trunc` the first expression in order to not defeat an index on  `QC.ModifiedDate` (if it exists).